# Can a semisimple orbit always be identified with a cotangent bundle?

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, sg.symplectic-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

Let $H$ be a semisimple element of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of a semisimple Lie group $G$, and let $M:=\mathrm{Ad}_G(H)\subset\mathfrak{g}$ be the corresponding adjoint orbit. If we choose a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ containing $H$ and a root system $\Phi$, then we have a splitting
$$
\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_{-1}\oplus\mathfrak{g}^H\oplus\mathfrak{g}_{+1}\, ,
$$
where $\mathfrak{g}_{\pm 1}$ is the sum of the $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$'s with $\alpha\in\Phi^{\pm}$ being a root such that $\alpha(H)\neq 0$, and $\mathfrak{g}^H$ is the centralizer of $H$ in $\mathfrak{g}$.

The tangent space at the origin to $M$ is then identified with the symplectic space $\mathfrak{g}_{-1}\oplus\mathfrak{g}_{+1}$.

I could then take a homogeneous manifold $F:=G/P$, **half the dimension** of $M$, where $P$ is a subgroup corresponding to the Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak{g}^H\oplus\mathfrak{g}_{+1}$, and consider its **cotangent bundle** $T^*F$: the tangent space to $T^*F$ at a given point can be identified with $\mathfrak{g}_{-1}\oplus\mathfrak{g}_{-1}^*$, which in turns is the same as $\mathfrak{g}_{-1}\oplus\mathfrak{g}_{+1}$, that is the tangent space to $M$ at the origin.

This reasoning lead me to suspect that maybe $M$ is (at least locally) isomorphic, as a symplectic manifold, to $T^*F$.

QUESTION: Is this true? If yes, under which additional hypotheses? If not, what can go wrong? Is this issue discussed somewhere in the literature?

Comment: Notice that for a compact Lie group $G$, $M$ is also compact whereas $T^*F$ is not, so there is in general no global isomorphism. 

The local question is not relevant since by Darboux theorem, every symplectic manifold is locally isomorphic to $T^* \mathbb{R}^n$. 
Finally, perhaps it helps to recall that there is a well-known canonical symplectic structure on co-adjoint orbits.